# Code that return True if only one or two of three params are true

Tags: c#, .net, programming-languages

I need a code that return True if only one or two of three params are true

what is the shortest/best way?

Comment: @Markust: That is true if any one is true, including when they are all true.

Comment: And what if all three are true?

Comment: @unholysampler: all trues is not covered in his example. for one, two or three I implied any. The spec is a little vague.

Comment: @Markust: "if only" is the same as "if and only if" in my book. But yes, the question could have been clearer.

Comment: yup. That's why I added the code not as an answer but as a comment. wasn't sure. :)

Comment: While we're arguing about the wording, I also don't think that "shortest/best" is very clearly defined. (But I have enjoyed the question - thanks!)

Comment: I'm not saying this belongs on code-golf, as it's a serious programming question, but I added the code-golf tag, as it *is* a code-golf.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm addicted to this question!

```
bool MyFourthAnswer(bool a, bool b, bool c)
{
   return (a != b) || (b != c);
}
```

Comment: +1: You outdid yourself. Not very important, but I'd wager this is the fastest of the answers so far too.

Comment: Thanks - I'm going "cold turkey" now - got to get away from this question :)

Comment: Similar but shorter: `return c^a|a^b;`  The question DID ask for "shortest".

Comment: How such a simple question can lead to so much answers, results and stuff. I'll run a benchmark against this one too (when I'm at a pc). I doubt if it's faster then the xor variant of Ben Voigt.

Comment: Fun, isn't it? Somewhere in the back of my mind, there's an "unsafe" implementation that takes the incoming params bool[] array, reads it as a byte[] array and then uses pointer hacks to read that as a single Int32... definitely not production code :)

Comment: @Stuart: I did a small benchmark (only 10 seconds each), but I suppose it's precise enough, your code with `||` replaced by `|`: 10183ms, `a ^ b | b ^ c`: 10050ms, `a ? (!b | !c) : (b | c)`: 10980ms. You won the race with production code :).

Comment: Thanks - superb work in doing the testing - as you said, "such a simple question" :)

Answer (score 14):

Just check whether at least one of the values is set *and* not all three values are set:

```
bool result = (a | b | c) & !(a & b & c);
```

Comment: @Aidiakapi I did no such thing. ;-) In fact, I originally misunderstood the question and my first answer would give a completely wrong result.

Comment: @Aidiakapi Your first answer was also false, that’s probably why. When I noticed that my answer was wrong I deleted it and only undeleted it *after* having corrected it, precisely to avoid downvotes.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph My first answer was corrected in several seconds, and twas because I misunderstood it. I thought just one of them was true, so I had `a || b || c`... But what I don't get is why people would upvote linq, I mean you're actually trying to make this take like 1000 times as intensive then that it really is :S. I'm going to benchmark that one.

Comment: A slightly faster solution would be:
bool result = (a || b || c) && !(a && b && c);

Comment: I'm surprised by the results of the benchmark, using | and & instead of || and &&, is a little bit over 1/7th faster. Your result: 594, my result: 700. Only difference is the & and the |...

Comment: @Aidiakapi: Considering performance is propably (assuming this isn't a core piece of some inner loop in a time-critical component) missing the point. The LINQ snippet clearly reflects the "1 or 2 are true" idea, by counting the true ones and comparing their count.

Comment: @Jonathan Stanton, you mean a slower solution would be? I benchmarked it, like I mentioned in the previous comment, so to prove it, I've done this test over 2000000000 times running, and with the doubles it's 13218ms, and with the singles it's 12086ms. Do the maths yourself ;)

Comment: @delnan So you're saying that storing a count, and then checking whenever that count is 1 or 2, is easier to read, then just seeing: if a, b, or c is true, and not a, b and c are true? That kinda makes it.

Comment: @Aidiakapi: Yes, as it's easier to match with OP's spec for me. And mind you, I'm completely comfortable with boolean algebra.

Comment: This solution runs 5 times faster than Stuarts answer, without being too verbose, yet easy to read, so it's better in my book.

Comment: @Martin I really doubt that. Slightly faster – maybe. Five times? Not plausible, unless the optimiser really sucks.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a fancy way:

```
bool oneOrTwoTrue = a ? (!b || !c) : (b || c);
```

If the first bool is set, either of the remaining should be unset. Otherwise, either of the of the remaining should be set.

EDIT- In response to comments: in production code, I would probably go with @AS-CII or @Stuart; it communicates the intent of what is being computed most clearly.

Comment: Love for ternary operator. +1

Comment: This doesn't seem like an ideal place to use the ternary operator (re: readability)

Comment: +1 from me too - but glad I don't have to read this in production code

Comment: It turns out to be extremely fast, this code is faster then any of the other solutions, it's 1/6th faster then the top voted answer ;).

Comment: I was interested in how much faster this precisely is, and it comes down to: `11.115833557937511662140028611117%` faster, so even though it takes a sec to figure out what it does, it's a lot faster then I expected. (I've been running the benchmark for a couple of minutes for each method.)

Answer (score 5):

This should do it

```
return !((a & b & c) || (!a & !b & !c))
```

Answer (score 5):

Another answer... I like this question...

```
bool MyThirdAnswer(params bool[] list)
{
   return list.Distinct().Count() == 2;
}
```

Comment: +1: This is the most creative answer! In fact, it's a nicer rephrasing of the question: "Check if the bools contain both a true and a   false".

Answer (score 4):

LINQ way:

```
bool[] params = { true, false, true };
int count = params.Count(a => a);
bool result = count == 2 || count == 1;
```

Comment: Didn't work for "all false" originally - but does now you've fixed it!

Comment: This is not the situation to use linq, it's much less fast.

Comment: This will return true if none of the inputs are true.  I like the idea though.

Comment: +1. One point; why not do `count == 1 || count == 2`? Easier to read IMO.

Comment: And I've just tested it, and linq is 15 times as slow!

Answer (score 4):

Final answer from me... honest!

One question that's occurred to me is whether this is really a situation where 3 bools should be used.

Instead of using 3 bools, it might be more appropriate to use a [Flags] enum - and it might make the code faster, more readable and more usable.

The code for this might be:

```
[flags]
enum Alarm
{
   None = 0x0,
   Kitchen = 0x1,
   Bathroom = 0x2,
   Bedroom = 0x4,
   All = Kitchen | Bathroom | Bedroom,
}

bool MyFifthAnswer(Alarm alarmState)
{
   switch (alarmState)
   {
       case Alarm.None:
       case Alarm.All:
          return false;
       default:
          return true;
   }
}
```

Out of interest, what are the 3 bools in the original question?

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, if true = 1 and false = 0:

```
return (a + b + c) % 3
```

And another one, assuming false = 0 and true = any strictly positive integer:

```
return (a*b + b*c + c*a) > (3*a*b*c)
```

Why stick to a couple comparisons / boolean operations when you could do 6 multiplications AND make it completely obscure? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
bool MyAnswer(params bool[] list)
{
   var countTrue = list.Where(x => x).Count();
   return countTrue == 1 || countTrue == 2;
}
```

**Edit:** after badgering by commenters `true == x` removed... sorry - this was in a "coding standards" document I had to follow once!

Comment: As much as I love fiddling with boolean algebra, I really like this one. (Missis one equals sign though, and the `== true` parts could be dropped).

Comment: Agreed - it should have been `true == x` :)

Comment: This will work however it is not the shortest way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

This is such a fun question - I had to try it in a Clojure (a language that I am learning)

```
(defn one-or-two-args-true? [& args]
      (> 3 (count (filter true? args)) 0))


user=> (one-or-two-args-true? false false false)
false
user=> (one-or-two-args-true? false false true)
true
user=> (one-or-two-args-true? false true true)
true
user=> (one-or-two-args-true? true true true)
false
```

Answer (score 1):

Since my previous answer was too long, I'll try again:

```
bool MySecondAnswer(params bool[] list)
{
   return list.GroupBy(x => x).Count() == 2;
}
```

Comment: Seriously, to all people trying to use linq for something so simple, firstly, it's 15 times slower, secondly it's a lot less readable, and thirdly, why would you? And for this one, the answer doesn't work... it must be count == 1 || count == 2.

Comment: I think the answer is what's "shortest/best"? If the question is for "fastest execution", then I agree that Linq is too slow - but if your idea of "Best" was, say, "most flexible for extension to additional parameters" then Linq is a really good answer (IMO)

Comment: Also... for this answer... your comment is wrong - this is a GroupBy solution - so `Count() == 1` would mean there was only one group.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you had the same as the other dude, but still, it's not what he asked, he asked specifically for 1 or 2 are right.

Comment: No worries - just enjoying the question - and I believe this yield the same answer as your "not all true and not all false" answer, albeit not as quickly!

Comment: Yes it does, since I suppose the GroupBy groups it, and since a boolean has only two options you're just checking to see if in the list there are two different options. So you're just checking that not all are false, and not all are true.

Answer (score 0):

Put the booleans in a list and then filter using linq:

```
var options = new List<bool>() { true, true, false };
var trueOptions = options.Where( opt => opt };
var count = trueOptions.Count();

return count == 1 || count == 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool result = !(a && b && c) && (a || b || c)
```

Comment: Honestly copy pasting the best voted answer, reversing the order, and making it doubles instead of singles doesn't make the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Good question
My Answer:

```
return (a||b||c) != (a&&b&&c)
```

Answer (score -1):

69 characters in bash

```
x (){ test "$(echo $@|sed 's/ /\n/g'|sort|uniq|grep -c .)" == "2"; }
```

32 characters in python

```
def x(a,b,c):return a!=b or b!=c
```

Comment: This answer seems to be unrelated to the question. The asker is looking for solutions in C#.

Comment: Whoops, sorry :(